# Rails ActiveRecord query using multiple joins involving polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to figure out how I can replicate the following SQL query using AR given the model definitions below. The cast is necessary to perform the average. The result set should group foo by bar (which comes from the polymorphic association). Any help is appreciated.

SQL:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(r.foo AS decimal)) "Average", s.bar
FROM rotation r INNER JOIN cogs c ON r.cog_id = c.id 
           INNER JOIN sprockets s ON s.id = c.crankable_id
           INNER JOIN machinists m ON r.machinist_id = m.id
WHERE c.crankable_type = 'Sprocket' AND 
      r.machine_id = 123 AND 
      m.shop_id = 1
GROUP BY s.bar
```

ActiveRecord Models:

```
class Rotation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cog
    belongs_to :machinist
    belongs_to :machine
end

class Cog < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :crankable, :polymorphic => true
    has_many :rotation
end

class Sprocket < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cogs, :as => :crankable
end

class Machinist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shop
end
```

**UPDATE**

I've figured out a way to make it work, but it feels like cheating. Is there are a better way than this?

```
Sprocket.joins('INNER JOIN cogs c ON c.crankable_id = sprockets.id', 
               'INNER JOIN rotations r ON r.cog_id = c.id',
               'INNER JOIN machinists m ON r.machinist_id = m.id')
    .select('sprockets.bar', 'r.foo')
    .where(:r => {:machine_id => 123}, :m => {:shop_id => 1})
    .group('sprockets.bar')
    .average('CAST(r.foo AS decimal)')
```

**SOLUTION**

Albin's answer didn't work as-is, but did lead me to a working solution. First, I had a typo in Cog and had to change the relation from:

```
has_many :rotation
```

to the plural form:

```
has_many :rotations
```

With that in place, I am able to use the following query

```
Sprocket.joins(cogs: {rotations: :machinist})
    .where({ machinists: { shop_id: 1 }, rotations: { machine_id: 123}})
    .group(:bar)
    .average('CAST(rotations.foo AS decimal)')
```

The only real difference is that I had to separate the where clause since a machine does not belong to a machinist. Thanks Albin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code is a little simpler and taking more help from AR

```
Sprocket
.joins(cogs: {rotations: :machinist})
.where({ machinists: { machine_id: 123, shop_id: 1 } } )
.group(:bar)
.average('CAST(rotations.foo AS decimal)')
```

The select clause was unnecessary, you don't have to select values since you only need them internally in the query, AR helps you decide what you need afterwards.

I tested this out using a similar structure in one of my own projects but it is not the exact same models so there might be a typo or something in there if it does not run straight up. I ran:

```
Activity
.joins(locations: {participants: :stuff})
.where({ stuffs: { my_field: 1 } })
.group(:title)
.average('CAST(participants.date_of_birth as decimal)')
```

producing this query

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(participants.date_of_birth as decimal)) AS average_cast_participants_date_of_birth_as_decimal, title AS title 
FROM `activities` 
INNER JOIN `locations` ON `locations`.`activity_id` = `activities`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `participants` ON `participants`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `stuffs` ON `stuffs`.`id` = `participants`.`stuff_id` 
WHERE `stuffs`.`my_field` = 1 
GROUP BY title
```

which AR makes in to a hash looking like this:

```
{"dummy title"=>#<BigDecimal:7fe9fe44d3c0,'0.19652273E4',18(18)>, "stats test"=>nil}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this didn't work exactly as-is, but led me to a working solution that doesn't require the raw SQL (aside from the cast). I will update the question with the final solution shortly.